# how to find which button is pressed?(android)

Tags: android

I working on simple calculator program. I'm trying to write a code that will return to me the ID of the button that i pressed (+,-,* or /).

what i did i used 2 TEXTBOX which one will keep a number & the "=" button will do the math & display the result on TX1. 
I tried to use SWITCH option. 
from some reason when I press the "=" it doesn't work.

I will appreciate any help from you guys.

```
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.view.MenuItem;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {  
private Button B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B0;   
private Button BMINUS,BSHAVE,BDIVIDE,BBACK,BCLEAR,BPOINT,BDUAL,BPLUS;  
private TextView TVDISPLAY,TVDISPLAY2;  
double x=0,y=0,z=0;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    B1.setOnClickListener(this);
    B2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2);
    B2.setOnClickListener(this);
    B3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt3);
    B3.setOnClickListener(this);
    B4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt4);
    B4.setOnClickListener(this);
    B5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt5);
    B5.setOnClickListener(this);
    B6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt6);
    B6.setOnClickListener(this);
    B7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt7);
    B7.setOnClickListener(this);
    B8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt8);
    B8.setOnClickListener(this);
    B9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt9);
    B9.setOnClickListener(this);
    B0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt0);
    B0.setOnClickListener(this);
    BMINUS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btsub);
    BMINUS.setOnClickListener(this);
    BSHAVE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btequal);
    BSHAVE.setOnClickListener(this);
    BPLUS= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btadd);
    BPLUS.setOnClickListener(this);
    BDIVIDE= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btdivide);
    BDIVIDE.setOnClickListener(this);
    BBACK= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btback);
    BBACK.setOnClickListener(this);
    BCLEAR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btclear);
    BCLEAR.setOnClickListener(this);
    BPOINT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btpoint);
    BPOINT.setOnClickListener(this);
    BDUAL = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btdual);
    BDUAL.setOnClickListener(this);
    TVDISPLAY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV1);
    TVDISPLAY.setOnClickListener(this);
    TVDISPLAY.setText(" ");
    TVDISPLAY.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // textview visible
    TVDISPLAY2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV2);
    TVDISPLAY2.setOnClickListener(this);
    TVDISPLAY2.setText(" ");
    TVDISPLAY2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // textview2 invisible

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void OnClickListener(){

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {       

     final int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.bt0:             
            if (TVDISPLAY.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            TVDISPLAY.setText(TVDISPLAY.getText() + "0");   
            }
            else {
                TVDISPLAY2.setText(TVDISPLAY2.getText() + "0"); 
            }
            break;
        case R.id.bt1:         
            if (TVDISPLAY.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                TVDISPLAY.setText(TVDISPLAY.getText() + "1");   
                }
                else {
                    TVDISPLAY2.setText(TVDISPLAY2.getText() + "1"); 
                }
                break;              
        case R.id.bt2:
            if (TVDISPLAY.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                TVDISPLAY.setText(TVDISPLAY.getText() + "2");   
                }
                else {
                    TVDISPLAY2.setText(TVDISPLAY2.getText() + "2"); 
                }
                break;
        case R.id.bt3:
            if (TVDISPLAY.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                TVDISPLAY.setText(TVDISPLAY.getText() + "3");   
                }
                else {
                    TVDISPLAY2.setText(TVDISPLAY2.getText() + "3"); 
                }
                break;
        case R.id.bt4:
            if (TVDISPLAY.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                TVDISPLAY.setText(TVDISPLAY.getText() + "4");   
                }
                else {
                    TVDISPLAY2.setText(TVDISPLAY2.getText() + "4"); 
                }
                break;
        case R.id.bt5:
            if (TVDISPLAY.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                TVDISPLAY.setText(TVDISPLAY.getText() + "5");   
                }
                else {
                    TVDISPLAY2.setText(TVDISPLAY2.getText() + "5"); 
                }
                break;
        case R.id.bt6:
            if (TVDISPLAY.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                TVDISPLAY.setText(TVDISPLAY.getText() + "6");   
                }
                else {
                    TVDISPLAY2.setText(TVDISPLAY2.getText() + "6"); 
                }
                break;
        case R.id.bt7:
            if (TVDISPLAY.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                TVDISPLAY.setText(TVDISPLAY.getText() + "7");   
                }
                else {
                    TVDISPLAY2.setText(TVDISPLAY2.getText() + "7"); 
                }
                break;
        case R.id.bt8:
            if (TVDISPLAY.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                TVDISPLAY.setText(TVDISPLAY.getText() + "8");   
                }
                else {
                    TVDISPLAY2.setText(TVDISPLAY2.getText() + "8"); 
                }
                break;
        case R.id.bt9:
            if (TVDISPLAY.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                TVDISPLAY.setText(TVDISPLAY.getText() + "9");   
                }
                else {
                    TVDISPLAY2.setText(TVDISPLAY2.getText() + "9"); 
                }
                break;
        case R.id.btadd: // add function
            AddFunc(x);                         break;
        case R.id.btclear: // clear
            TVDISPLAY.setText(" "); 
            TVDISPLAY2.setText(" ");            break;
        case R.id.btback: // back
            BackFunc();                         break;
        case R.id.btdivide: // divide
            DevFunc(id);                        break;      
        case R.id.btdual: // Kefel
            DualFuncdual(id);                   break;
        case R.id.btequal: // Shave             
            EqualFunc(v);                   break;
        case R.id.btpoint: // Nekuda
            TVDISPLAY.setText(TVDISPLAY.getText() + ".");   
            Nekuda();                           break;// will check if there is a point in the number
        case R.id.btsub: // Sub
            SubFunc(id);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            intent = intent.putExtra("TVDISPLAY", TVDISPLAY.getText().toString());

        }       
}   

private double EqualFunc(View v) { 
    // will get the id of the button that pressed
    // check which button is pressed by id.
    Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
    switch (clickedButton.getId()) {

    case R.id.btadd:    // add        
        y=Double.parseDouble(TVDISPLAY2.getText().toString());      
        z=x+y;     
            TVDISPLAY.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TVDISPLAY2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            TVDISPLAY.setText(Double.toString(z));

    break;

    case R.id.btsub:     // sub

        y=Double.parseDouble(TVDISPLAY2.getText().toString());      
    z=x-y;     
        TVDISPLAY.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TVDISPLAY2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        TVDISPLAY.setText(Double.toString(z));
    break;

    case R.id.btdual: // dual

        y=Double.parseDouble(TVDISPLAY2.getText().toString());      
        z=x*y;     
        TVDISPLAY.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TVDISPLAY2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        TVDISPLAY.setText(Double.toString(z));

    break;

    case (R.id.btdivide):    // divide

        y=Double.parseDouble(TVDISPLAY2.getText().toString());      
        z=x/y;     
        TVDISPLAY.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TVDISPLAY2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        TVDISPLAY.setText(Double.toString(z));
    }
    return z;       
}

private double SubFunc(double x2) { // still empty

    x=Double.parseDouble(TVDISPLAY.getText().toString());
    TVDISPLAY.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    TVDISPLAY2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return R.id.btsub;  
}

private double DevFunc(double x2) {// still empty
    x=Double.parseDouble(TVDISPLAY.getText().toString());
    TVDISPLAY.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    TVDISPLAY2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return R.id.btdivide;
}   

private double DualFuncdual(double x2) {            
    x=Double.parseDouble(TVDISPLAY.getText().toString());
    TVDISPLAY.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    TVDISPLAY2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return R.id.btdual;
}

private double AddFunc( double x2) { // doesn't work.
    x=Double.parseDouble(TVDISPLAY.getText().toString());
    TVDISPLAY.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    TVDISPLAY2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return x;
}
```

}

Comment: where is = functionality written?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Does that class implement "OnClickListener" ? have you setOnClickListener on the bnts?

You should do v.findViewById(R.id.THE_BTN_ID);

Comment: When are you calling this function?

Comment: You didn't wrote the code for the '=' ... so it don't work.

Comment: I add the all code here

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring android:onClick="btn1" or btn2 or btn3 etc...

and to get their functions all you need to do is declare

> public void btn1(View v)
>
> {
>
> //functions here
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code that Mike posted. 
Or you can do it like this:

```
clickedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
```

everytime that the button 'clickedButton' is clicked, the method 'onClick(View v)' is called

Or your can implements the interface 'OnClickListener' on your class, register the listener to your class, like this:

```
 clickedButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And then, on the method 'public void onClick(View v)' you can put something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.clickedButtonId :
      //Do Stuff
      break;

    default:
      break;
   }
}
```